# SavedStateHandle ViewModel Not Preserving State Across Navigation and Stack Clearing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have an Android application with multiple screens managed by Jetpack Navigation. In my app, I'm using a `SavedStateHandle` in my ViewModel to preserve certain states across configuration changes and navigation events. Specifically, I have a scenario where I navigate from `ScreenFirst` to `ScreenSecond`, and on `ScreenSecond`, I toggle the visibility of a button based on the value of `isBackButtonVisible`.

However, despite saving this value in the `SavedStateHandle`, when I press the Back button to return to `ScreenFirst` and then navigate back to `ScreenSecond`, the visibility of the button is always reset to its initial state (false), instead of retaining the previously set value.

Additionally, I want to clear the back stack when navigating from one screen to another to ensure a consistent navigation flow. Although I've implemented `popUpTo` to clear the back stack, it doesn't seem to affect the preservation of the `isBackButtonVisible` value.

How can I ensure that the `SavedStateHandle` in my ViewModel preserves the state across navigation events and back stack clearing? What could be causing the issue with the state not being retained properly?

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandle
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.SavedStateHandleSaveableApi
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.saveable
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import org.koin.androidx.compose.navigation.koinNavViewModel

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            NavigationScreen()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun NavigationScreen(navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "ScreenFirst",
        route = "parentRoute"
    ) {

        composable("ScreenFirst") {
            Button(onClick = {
                navController.navigateWithClearStack("ScreenSecond")
            }) {
                Text(text = "Move to Second Screen")
            }
        }

        composable("ScreenSecond") {

            val viewModel: SecondViewModel = koinNavViewModel()

            Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                Button(onClick = { viewModel.update(true) }) {
                    Text(text = "Show Back Button")
                }

                AnimatedVisibility(visible = viewModel.isBackButtonVisible) {
                    Button(onClick = {
                        navController.navigateWithClearStack("ScreenFirst")
                    }) {
                        Text(text = "Move to Back Screen")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun NavController.navigateWithClearStack(screenRoute: String) {
    this.navigate(screenRoute) {
        // Clear the back stack up to the start destination
        popUpTo(currentBackStackEntry?.destination?.route ?: return@navigate) {
            inclusive = true
        }
        // Specify the new start destination
        launchSingleTop = true
    }
}

class SecondViewModel(savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {

    @OptIn(SavedStateHandleSaveableApi::class)
    var isBackButtonVisible by savedStateHandle.saveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
        private set

    fun update(value: Boolean) {
        isBackButtonVisible = value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [table](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states#options). The `SavedStateHandle` does not survive when user navigates between screens. It can return value if app crash or orientation changed, but not when user pressed back button.

If you logic need to save state forever, use persistent storage, for example, [DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore). If logic need to save value just for current session, you can use `SharedViewModel` between fragments or fragment and parent activity ([guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate)). Or transfer data with navigation component on both directions when navigate to destination with [args](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/use-graph/safe-args).